# Javascript or jQuery selector from `a` then to much div using class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have html like this

```
<a href="/portal/product/62157993" id="ember1708" class="product-items__item ember-view"> 
  <div id="ember1709" class="product-item product-view-item ember-view">
    <div class="product-item__info">
      <div class="product-item__name">
        <span data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1712="1712">Pashmina Denim</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-item__promote">
        <!---->
        <div id="ember1713" class="product-boost-button ember-view">
          <div id="ember1714" class="shopee-button shopee-button--inactive shopee-button--medium ember-view">  Promote
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Now, I want to click DIV with TEXT "Promote" using `a href="/portal/product/62157993"` selector using CLASS only, not using ID

I have tried with the below code but is not working in my case

```
var aTags = document.querySelectorAll("a[href='/portal/product/62157993'],div[class='product-item'],div[class='product-item__info'],div[class='product-item__promote'],div[class='product-boost-button]',div[class='product-boost-button]',div[class='shopee-button]'");
```

How can i resolve this ?

Comment: Seems like ember, why you are attaching click event this way, instead of following ember's guideline?

Comment: Why are you trying to click a div element? Divs have no click behaviour save that which you add via JS, and you shouldn't add any via JS because it's an accessibility fail for people who can't use a mouse.

Comment: div with class shopee-button is button  @nnnnnn

Comment: So you're saying it is accessible by keyboard, even though it's a div element?

Comment: I want to click this div only with class, because id's random @azs06

Comment: No, I want to accessing with mouse @nnnnnn

Comment: You're missing my point: some users don't have a mouse, or are physically unable to use anything but a keyboard. Those users would not be able to use your page. If you use a real button or anchor element (styled if you like) those users can "click" it via the keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to select specific child element of `<a href="/portal/product/62157993" id="ember1708" class="product-items__item ember-view">` you could do it like this.

```js
var promote = document.querySelector('.product-items__item  .product-item__promote');


promote.addEventListener('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 console.log('prmotion ending');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/portal/product/62157993" id="ember1708" class="product-items__item ember-view"> 
  <div id="ember1709" class="product-item product-view-item ember-view">
    <div class="product-item__info">
      <div class="product-item__name">
        <span data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-1712="1712">Pashmina Denim</span>
      </div>
      <div class="product-item__promote">
        <div id="ember1713" class="product-boost-button ember-view">
          <div id="ember1714" class="shopee-button shopee-button--inactive shopee-button--medium ember-view">Promote
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
</body>
```

This would make sure that you are only selecting promote which are child of `.product-items__item` class.

Comment: Perfect :) , I'm modified to `document.querySelector('a[href="/portal/product/62157993"] .product-item__promote .shopee-button');` because I have many more link. Thank You